# jQuery - toggle display of a string of comma deliminated values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within a table I have a column which contains a list of values which are comma deliminated.

The action I want to achieve is that clicking on the deliminated text will 'roll-up the text to display just the first value.  Clicking again would once again display all values.

My intent is to use a + and - sign to show the state.

String example: 
"Red, Blue, Green"

Collapsed display:
+ Red

Expanded display:
- Red
Blue
Green

Comment: No code yet.  I wasn't sure where to begin; thinking there might be a 'parser' type function rather than me brute forcing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an element with id=rgb:

```
$('#rgb').click( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    if( text[0] == '+' ) {
        $this.text($this.data('hiddenText'));
    } else {
        $this.data('hiddenText', text);
        var index = text.indexOf(',');
        if(index >= 0) {
            $this.text('+' + text.substr(1,index-1));
        }
    }
});
```

On [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDeE2/)

---

Version where +/- is not part of element:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDeE2/3/)

```
$('#rgb').click( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var index = text.indexOf(',');
    if( index < 0) {
        if ($this.data('hiddenText') !== undefined) {
            $this.text($this.data('hiddenText'));
        }
    } else {
        $this.data('hiddenText', text);
        $this.text(text.substr(0,index));            
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you.  I'm thinking the + and - will not be part of the text so no need to include it.  Cna the toggling be done solely on whether there is a comma?

Comment: I updated fiddle to include what I'm thinking.  It toggles on whether or not there is a comma.  I can then add code to toggle a +- image icon.

Comment: The 'hiddentext' works as a local variable within the function?  I want to be able to have the text collapsed on page loading.
Thanks for your great help!

Comment: 'hiddentext' is attached to the DOM element, so you can read/write it from anywhere else

Comment: Ah ok.  how might I set all collapsed when the page first loads?  I would use .trigger('click') in some way?

Comment: It might not be the most elegant, but now it is the easiest: just use $('.rgb').click()

Comment: This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/XDeE2/8/

Comment: Yes, that is nice. Or is it a question?

Comment: No question.  Thanks for your excellent help!  It really pointed a jquery newbie into the right direction.

Comment: Would you then mark my answer as accepted?